# Linking a contact to user

Tags: unit-test, contact, user

I am trying to link a contact to a user object in test case. However, it seems that user.contact = contact doesn't work and user.contactId = contact.id will cause an error saying contactId field is not writable. Any suggestions?

Comment: are u trying to create community user?

Comment: No, I am just getting the current user info from the database. But user info is able to be seen without using seealldata, but contacts are not. So I am linking the user to a new contact in my test case.

Comment: you OWD for User must be Read Only, that's why you are seeing all the users. Also you can't change the Contact associated with an user object. See this thread for more information  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17102/can-you-change-the-related-contact-of-a-customer-portal-user                                                                                                        Instead of liking an existing user you could create a new user in the test class and associate that user with the contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the Contact associated with an user object. See [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17102/can-you-change-the-related-contact-of-a-customer-portal-user) thread for more information. Instead of liking an existing user you could create a new user in the test class and associate that user with the contact. See [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/ExampleApexCustomerPortalUser) thread for creating user in test class.