# Connect a new portal user with existing contact or Update the User.ContactID with existing Contact.ID

Tags: apex, user, customer-portal

I am trying to create a Portal User without creating a contact and want to link the User with existing contact. But somehow I am unable to do this and now I want to update the User.contactID with existingContact.ID and it is giving me the error saying "Field is not writable" Any solution for this here is my code.

```
String profileId = conf.ProfileId__c; 
            String accountId = Process_Builder_Settings__c.getInstance().Account_New_User__c;            
            String userName = contactObject.Email;      
            contactObject.AccountId = accountId;

            u.Username = contactObject.Email;
            u.Email = contactObject.Email;
            u.FirstName = contactObject.FirstName;
            u.LastName = contactObject.LastName;
            u.LanguageLocaleKey = getLocale();
            u.CommunityNickname = contactObject.FirstName + contactObject.LastName + '_' + Datetime.now().millisecond();
            u.CommunityNickname = u.CommunityNickname.length() > 40 ? u.CommunityNickname.substring(40) : u.CommunityNickname;
            u.ProfileId = profileId;
            u.ContactId = contactObject.Id; 

            String userId = null;

        if(existingContact.Id != null){
            u.ContactId = existingContact.Id;
            u.alias = contactObject.FirstName.substring(1,1) + contactObject.LastName.abbreviate(6);
            u.timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
            u.emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8';
            u.localesidkey = 'en_US';
            insert u; 
            userId = u.Id;

        }

         else {
            if(!Test.isRunningTest())
                userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, null);
            else 
                userId = createPortalUserForTest('tportaluser@ibtest.org',ContactObject,'en_US','Customer Community Basic');

        }

        List<contact> dupContact = [ Select User__c,ID, FirstName, Job_title__C from contact where FirstName = :contactObject.FirstName AND LastName = :contactObject.LastName  AND ( BirthDate = :contactObject.Birthdate OR Country_of_Birth__c = :contactObject.Country_of_Birth__c )   AND Id  in (SELECT ContactId From User  where isActive = FALSE) AND Deceased__c = FALSE  ];
        List<User> newlyCreatedUser = [ Select ContactID from User where ID = : newUser.ID];

        if( !newlyCreatedUser.isEmpty()  && !dupContact.isempty() )
        {
            newlyCreatedUser[0].ContactID = dupContact[0].id;
            update  newlyCreatedUser[0];
        }


         if(!dupContact.isEmpty())
         {
             dupContact[0].User__C= userId;
             dupContact[0].Job_title__C = ' Dev';                   

               update dupContact[0];                 
         }
```

Comment: can you please check this sales force stack exchange post,it will helpful to you:https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17102/can-you-change-the-related-contact-of-a-customer-portal-user

Comment: Yup, I've gone through this thread, but I badly want to implement this functionality, either doesn't create the Contact or update the User.ContactID. Is there any way or workaround other then disable the user then creating the new user?

Comment: What is contactObject?  Is this an existing contact?  Does it have an active portal user linked to it?